# Find characters that do not match a given regex

Tags: python, regex

I am writing a program to validate and correct a given date as a string. Lets take `04121987` as the date in the format `ddmmyyyy`. A regular expression for such a date:

```
(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])(0[1-9]|1[012])(19\d\d|20\d\d)
```

If I match my string with the regular expression it works well. In Python:

```
>>> regex = re.compile(r'(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])(0[1-9]|1[012])(19\d\d|20\d\d)')
>>> regex.findall('04121987')
[('04', '12', '1987')]
```

If I have a string `04721987` one can clearly see `72` is not a valid month and thus the string will not match the regex.

```
>>> regex.findall('04721987')
[]
```

What I would like to find out is the character which causes the regex to fail and its position. In this case it is `7`. How could I do this in Python?

Comment: Consider month `13`. Neither character fails the regex by itself, it is the combination of the two.

Comment: The regex for month is `(0[1-9]|1[012])` and it does fail.

Comment: Yes, but should we blame the `1` or the `3` for the failure? This question would be more complex with some other regexes, so I'm not surprised that there is no such reporting functionality built into the regex engine.

Comment: Oh, yes you are right. I did not see it that way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe what you want isn't possible, because `_sre` module is implemented in *C* ;(.

You could try using [this package](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/_sre.py) instead (by monkey patching `sre_compile`, modifying the path and importing your new `_sre`first, etc.) but I don't think it worths it. It is an implementation of the `_sre` package fully written in Python, so you'll be able to see the source code, edit it, and do something right when the next character doesn't match.

You could do a similar thing by either:

- Splitting the date string in 3 (day, month and year) and matching the regular expressions independently
- validating the date time using another way that doesn't involve regex

Perhaps you don't obtain the *exact* digit where the error is, but I don't think it makes too much sense in this scenario, as long as you tell the user what is wrong (day, month or year).

Answer (score 2):

One possible approach is to construct a regex that matches anything, but places the good matches and bad matches in different groups. Examine which groups are populated in the results to know which group failed.

```
>>> regex = re.compile(r'(?:(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])|(.{,2}))(?:(0[1-9]|1[012])|(.{,2}))(?:(19\d\d|20\d\d)|(.{,4}))')
>>> regex.match('04121987').groups()
('04', None, '12', None, '1987', None)
>>> regex.match('04721987').groups()
('04', None, None, '72', '1987', None)
>>> regex.match('0412').groups()
('04', None, '12', None, None, '')
```

---

Another approach is to take a suitable valid string as the basis, and replace it by the input string character by character, and validate on each iteration. Here I use `datetime.datetime.strptime` to validate. You could use a regex as well, though it would have to accept years up to 2999, so the one in the question does not work.

```
from datetime import datetime

def str_to_date(s):
    good_date = '01011999'
    for i in xrange(len(good_date)):
        try:
            d = datetime.strptime(s[:i+1] + good_date[i+1:], '%d%m%Y')
        except ValueError:
            raise ValueError("Bad character '%s' at index %d" % (s[i:i+1], i))
    return d
```

Answer (score 1):

This solution is a beast and I hope you find a better method.  This code is lightly tested and might be sufficient.  The errorindex() function takes a date as a string and returns a list of indexes of incorrect entries.  There are ambiguities though if the 1st month digit is incorrect.  It is impossible to determine if the 2nd digit is correct or not without knowing the 1st.  Here is the code.  Note: I forgot about leap years!

```
def errorindex(s):
  err = []
  for i in range(len(s)):
    if i == 0:  #month1
      if int(s[i]) < 0 or int(s[i]) > 1:
        err.append(i)
    if i == 1:  #month2
      if int(s[i-1]) == 0:
        if int(s[i]) < 1 or int(s[i]) > 9:
          err.append(i)
      elif int(s[i-1]) == 1:
        if int(s[i]) < 0 or int(s[i]) > 2:
          err.append(i)
      else:
        if int(s[i]) < 0 or int(s[i]) > 2:
          err.append(i)
    if i == 2:  #day1
      if int(s[i]) < 0 or int(s[i]) > 3:
        err.append(i)
    if i == 3:  #day2
      if int(s[i-1]) in [0,1,2] and str(s[:2]) != '02':
        if int(s[i]) < 0 or int(s[i]) > 9:
          err.append(i)
      elif int(s[i-1]) in [0,1,2] and str(s[:2]) == '02':
        if int(s[i]) < 0 or int(s[i]) > 8:
          err.append(i)
    if i == 4:  #year1
      if int(s[i]) < 1 or int(s[i]) > 2:
        err.append(i)
    if i == 5:  #year2
      if int(s[i-1]) == 1:
        if int(s[i]) != 9:
          err.append(i)  
      elif int(s[i-1]) == 2:
        if int(s[i]) != 0:
          err.append(i)
    if i ==6:
      if int(s[i]) < 0 or int(s[i]) > 9:
        err.append(i)
    if i ==7:
      if int(s[i]) < 0 or int(s[i]) > 9:
        err.append(i)
  return err

s = '04721987'  

print(errorindex(s))
```

Comment: I didn't account for the correct values for months with 30 or more days.  I suggest using the datetime module.  You could have a good known date and swap out a portion with your string to verify if the date is in the range.  It is a little more complicated than just one good known date, but it is a start.

Answer (score 0):

Well the most obvious answer to me, is to use some regex library that uses finite automatons or write your own. Than you can, with some modifications, precisely determine where it failed. But I assume that is not what you are willing to do.

Otherwise if you know, that the input will have the exact size, the exact date format, you can divide it into 3 sectors - dd mm yyyy and than try to apply respectively the regular expressions for every single character separately. It is not very nice solution but you will get what you want.

Comment: I did think of writing an automaton but was thinking if there'd be an easier solution :)

Comment: Hmm I understand... But I don't think that there is any nicer and cleaner solution than building your own automaton. You can implement it using array and it won't take very long to write since inputs are very limited. And actually, few months ago I wrote my own automation generator from regular expressions, so if you are interested, I can generate the automatons table for you.

Comment: I appreciate it. Its always better to look at anothers' implementation.